# Diferença entre keyup(), keydown() e keypress()

Tags: jquery, html

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre `keyup()`, `keydown()` e `keypress()`, na minha opinião acho que fazem a mesma coisa, mas qual a finalidade de cada um?

Melhoria de desempenho para cada tipo?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Na verdade não fazem a mesma coisa.

**keyup()**: o evento ocorre quando a tecla retorna à posição original no teclado (i.e. quando você solta a mesma).

**keydown()**: o evento ocorre quando a tecla **é** pressionada. O evento repete enquanto a tecla estiver pressionada (exceto para as teclas **Ctrl**, **Alt** e **Shift**).

**keypress()**: o evento ocorre quando a tecla **está** pressionada. O evento repete enquanto a tecla estiver pressionada (exceto para as teclas **Ctrl**, **Alt** e **Shift**).

A diferença entre **keydown()** e **keypress()** está que o segundo não é capturado quando as teclas **Ctrl**, **Alt** ou **Shift** são pressionadas.

Comment: Se forem utilizados para captura das teclas, apenas o keypress é case-sensitive.

Comment: Valeu parceiro, tmj!

Comment: Show de boleta.